# selecting a day of the week every x number of days thats not a weekend

Tags: php

I have code already for a date range that works fairly well (not using datetime class, I'm stuck in 5.2). But I want to modify it to select the previous day before the weekend (e.g. friday) based on every fortnight from the starting date.

I have been experimenting with finding all the saturdays and sundays then doing a `array_search` with a `mktime` as such: `mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", $date), date("d", $date)-1, date("Y", $date)`

It seems to find all the Saturdays & Sundays but my code seems replace the actual dates instead of just selecting the previous day and styling it.

My code is a bit of a mess, but its pretty generic date range, e.g. while `($date1 <= $date2) { do stuff here }`

So how can I select the friday before a weekend of a number of every 14 days from the start date.

Edit:
The answers below were all fine, but not quite what I was asking. Hopefully I can be more clear here.
I don't want code that finds me all the fridays in a date range specifically, I want to do a date range and every time there is a friday that is +14 days from the start date (i.e. every 2 weeks) I want to style it so it stands out. I have managed to find all the weekends every 2 weeks and style it, but I can't figure out how to select the friday's 2 weeks in advance from the start date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php)  to get the initial Friday and then you can either use that or your mktime function to do your 14 day adds.

Answer (score 0):

```
$thisWeekFriday = strtotime('friday');
$twoWeeksFromFriday = $thisWeekFriday + 1209600; //1209600 seconds in two weeks
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $twoWeeksFromFriday);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$number_of_dates = 10;
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_dates; $i++) {
   echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Friday +' . ($i * 2) . ' weeks'));
}
```

today this would output

```
2011-08-12
2011-08-26
2011-09-09
2011-09-23
2011-10-07
2011-10-21
2011-11-04
2011-11-18
2011-12-02
2011-12-16
```